# My MySQL password changed and the file "my.ini" deleted

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I've installed MySQL 8.0 and I was trying to change mysql password using [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html).

But unfortunately I deleted the file "my.ini" before specifying it as "--defaults-file".
So after that, I couldn't start SQL services.
I found that the solution is to run install&--initialize command in administrator mode on CMD.
Even though after that MySQL service started and  MySQL-workbench started too, MySQL-workbench ask me password but nothing work for it (previous and new password doesn't work for it).

Now is there any way to solve this problem (reset password without file my.ini

Thanks.